# How to get column names that have different values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Is there any way to find out column names that do not have same values among two or more records returned by a query?
I am using ActiveRecord on Rails.

The following code returns a number of records (greater than 1 in my case):

```
TableName.where(column_1: value)
```

If the above query returns three records, I want to know if there is a way I can compare the three records and get the column names where values do not match or are different?

For example if the above query returns these records:

```
 column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4
----------|----------|----------|----------
   value  |    A     |    B     |    C
   value  |    A     |    B     |    C1
   value  |    A     |    B     |    C2
```

How can I compare the above three records and find out which columns have different values? (column_4 in this case). In my original database, I have more than 25 columns and I would need all column names wherever there is a difference.

Note: The query results are returned in an array form and each column can be accessed using `records[i].column_name`.

Also I need to get this working on Ruby with ActiveRecord as the wrapper. I think this can be done using a large number of nested `if`/`else` but there must be an elegant solution to this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Filter all the columns that have a unique value of more than one.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Database is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

You may receive necessary columns in Ruby:

```
columns = [:column_2, :column_3, :column_4]
various_columns = []
records = TableName.where(column_1: value)
columns.each do |column|
  various_columns << column if records.map(&column).uniq.count > 1
end
```

or may you put count logic to database with query like this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT column_2) AS count_column_2,
  COUNT(DISTINCT column_3) AS count_column_3,
  COUNT(DISTINCT column_4) AS count_column_4
FROM table_name
WHERE column_1 = value
```

Ruby code to process that logic:

```
columns = [:column_2, :column_3, :column_4]
selects = 
  columns.map do |column|
    "COUNT(DISTINCT #{column}) AS count_#{column}"
  end.join(", ")
record = TableName.select(selects).take(1).first
various_columns = columns.select { |column| record["count_#{column}"] > 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using ruby instead of sql you can do this

```
relation = Table.where(:column_1 => "thing")
relation_size = relation.count

Table.column_names.select do |column_name|
  relation.pluck(column_name).uniq.size != relation_size
end
```